# Only display one instance of a ruby hash if certain parameters match within the first 8 characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have narrowed down the number of `Properties` in the `@properties` hash through parameters sent through a form from a user, now here's the issue --

There are many properties in the database that have similar street addresses (up to the first 8 characters) and I would like to **only display one of those properties in my view** instead of 5 or 7 or 14.  The code below is how I am trying to accomplish this, but it seems to not be working.  Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Here's the index action in the controller --

```
def index
    @properties = Property.all
    @properties = @properties.where("bedrooms = ?", params[:bedrooms])                        if params[:bedrooms].present?
    @properties = @properties.text_search(params[:query])                                     if params[:query].present?
    @properties = @properties.area_search(params[:area])                                      if params[:area].present?
    @properties = @properties.where("month_available = ?", params[:availability])             if params[:availability].present?
    @properties = @properties.where(Date.today.mon <= :month_available <= Date.today.mon + 2) if params[:now].present?
    @properties = @properties.page(params[:page]).per(30)
end
```

Here's the view (views/properties/index.html.erb) --

```
<% @properties.uniq {|p| [p.latitude, p.longitude, p.street_address[0..7]]}.each do |property| %>
    <%= render "property", :property => property %>
<% end %>
```

And here is the schema for the table in the database --

```
create_table "properties", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "street_address"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "zipcode"
    t.string   "short_description"
    t.text     "long_description"
    t.integer  "rent"
    t.string   "application_fee"
    t.string   "bedrooms"
    t.string   "bathrooms"
    t.string   "vacancy_status"
    t.string   "month_available"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "latitude"
    t.string   "longitude"
    t.string   "images",            default: [], array: true
    t.string   "amenities",         default: [], array: true
    t.string   "year_ready"
end
```

Comment: These properties all have the same latitude and longitude?

Comment: @coreyward - yes, they are actually individual units inside of a single building.  The units that are all inside of the same building have identical lat and lng coordinates listed in the DB.

Comment: What's the problem with that code?

Comment: @mdesantis - it's not working.  It is still pulling all of properties instead of limiting the properties displayed in my view.

Comment: I see there is a pagination. Does your issue raise on different pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `@properties` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, then the `uniq` method isn’t the same as the [`Array#uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) method from core Ruby. In Active Record the [`uniq` method is an alias](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.2/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L721) of the [`distinct` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-distinct), which doesn’t do anything with the block that is passed. Since in Ruby you  can pass a block to any method, it is effectively ignored.

You can convert your results into an array with `to_a`, and then use the `Array#uniq` method on that:

```
@properties.to_a.uniq {|p| [p.latitude, p.longitude, p.street_address[0..7]]}.each do |property|
  # as before ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, not just for the answer, but for the additional information and reading material about Ruby.  More educational endeavors are always appreciated.